# nginx : rewrite utf8 : why lower case

Tags: utf-8, nginx, url-rewriting

I have some routes that was previously with uppercase for language and now I want lowrcase.
here is a route : /Ka/განცხადებები that should simply become /ka/განცხადებები

in my conf
        if ($uri ~ ^/K(.+)){
          set $bb $1;
          rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://$host/k$bb permanent;
        }

and I cant understand why but 
/ka/%E1%83%92%E1%83%90%E1%83%9C%E1%83%AA%E1%83%AE%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%94%E1%83%91%E1%83%98/

become

/ka/%e1%83%92%e1%83%90%e1%83%9c%e1%83%aa%e1%83%ae%e1%83%90%e1%83%93%e1%83%94%e1%83%91%e1%83%94%e1%83%91%e1%83%98

ie all uppercase letter become lowercase, that cause à pb with my rails app.

does anyone know why nginx do this ? and is it possible to block this ?

I can't just uppercase everything as there is some latin letter and my routes are case sensitive

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the real problem. This should not be a problem for your rails app, since these URLs are identical. I suspect nginx decodes the url for matching and when it has to rewrite the url reencodes it using lowercase.
Also, unless you really need the $bb variable somewhere down the line, this can be done a lot easier:

```
location ~ ^/K[a-z]/.*$ {
    rewrite ^/K([a-z])/(.*)$ /k$1/$2;
}
```

Comment: actually it is as I'm using route-translator gem :-s
$bb what this to avoid one regex, but maybe it is useless. Ive just read somewhere there variables "cost" nothink compare to regexp.

Comment: Then complain with the devs of that route translator gem, that they should be case insensitive. Variables are negligible, but it isn't the only optimization I've made.